# Azure Web Apps - List and Web Apps - List Functions Rest API response is empty

Tags: azure, function, rest, api

[API execution Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9ow8.jpg)

I have two azure Accounts [Account1 and Account2].

**Account1 has less than 10 functions and Apps**

- Following API execution works fine and getting proper response

**Account2 has 1000+ functions and Apps**.

- Following API execution doesn't work and response is empty.

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2019-08-01

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/functions?api-version=2019-08-01

Is it a problem with azure API or I'm I missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the api for getting the websites list , it worked for me. Under my subscription , i have 93 websites and overall resulting data was 42.84 KB in size.

I would suggest you to check the Bearer token and the permission set for the service principal you are using to query the data:

[image]

[image]

P.S. Same is with Function rest api  too.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Permission looks good, i need to cross check with my azure admin.                             API execution is very inconsistent ,  Sometimes it works and most of the time it fails. Even though execution status code is 200 but no/empty response.